# Breeze type getProperty method does not work with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, breeze

The breeze [docs](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/validation.html) show this to get the property type for a property on an entity:

```
//get the Person type
var personType = em.metadataStore.getEntityType("Person"); 
//get the property definition to validate
var websiteProperty = personType.getProperty("website");
```

But if you are using Typescript this does not work.

The type definitions for `MetadataStore.getEntityType` returns an `IStructuralType`.  But `getProperty` is on `EntityType` and not on `IStructuralType`.

`EntityType` does implement `IStructuralType`, but there is no guarantee that the `IStructuralType` is an `EntityType`.

**Is this an error in the typing for Breeze?  Or is there another way to get this method call?**

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Cast it: `em.metadataStore.getEntityType("Person") as EntityType;`
2. Change the definition of `getEntityType` to return an `EntityType` in your `.d.ts` file

Keep in mind that changing type information is always safe - the worst you can ever do is cause a TypeScript compile error. This is because all type information is erased. (The exception is changing the name or extends of a class, since that is compiled to js.)